# Displays, camera, speakers, microphones: why after more than 50 years of development do they still need calibration?

Tags: microphone, display, camera, speakers

An old question running through my mind:

Displays, camera, speakers, microphones: why after more than 50 years of development do they still need calibration?

Whatever cheap or high-end material I come across in the reviews I read from time to time, none seams to be properly calibrated.

There is enough research and commercial competition over these transducer categories for a time long enough to make this intriguing...

Comment: Calibrated in what way?

Comment: Because randomness is a thing.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to calibrate a microphone in the factory, if, for example, the acoustic properties of the room it's used in will force the user to recalibrate it anyway.

Comment: Flat frequency response for audio transducers and delta-E (for example) zeroing for optic ones.

Comment: @The photon Of course but there are IEC/ANSI standards providing conditions of measure for all these peripherals. There are also "normal use" conditions like earphones in the ear. My point is that despite wishing to provide a nice user experience and a response the closest to the reality, manufacturer and companies doesn't appear to go very far in this last  direction.

Comment: @user9020 - regards your last point in your comment immediately above, what evidence do you have to suggest "companies doesn't appear to go very far in this last direction".

Comment: You're right.. It's a subjective opinion. It is more the sum of reviews I stumbled upon across the years when I needed a camera/screen display/earphone...

Comment: @user9020 [Broad question calls for a short broad answer.]  Because precise calibration costs money.  The majority of the consumer level users don't require fine level of calibration.  Those who require fine calibration can take care of it by taking their device to a calibration service and paying the aforementioned money.

Comment: @user9020 From the EE.SE standpoint, there are two problems with this question.  (1) It's too broad, because it covers displays, camera, speakers, microphones... all of those.  (2) This is a prosumer question, or an operations question. This is not an electronics design question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calibration is expensive. Regarding consumer equipment, most users want less expensive product and do not mind small deviations. If you are willing to pay, you can get very precise stuff with decades of research in it.

Comment: ... and re-calibrate it every year or so.